# Can index.js be blank in node.js projects? I'm using Heroku for app deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku

Basically, I'm working on a school project -- currently trying to test the login page. I'm using Heroku to deploy this project, but I keep getting the below error. I'm wondering if it has something to do with index.js? My Procfile has the line:

```
web: node src/[app name].js
```

Note: [app name] isn't the actual app name. I replaced it for privacy reasons.

```
2022-10-22T17:19:11.562569+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/src/[app name].js'

2022-10-22T17:19:11.562570+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)

2022-10-22T17:19:11.562570+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)

2022-10-22T17:19:11.562570+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)

2022-10-22T17:19:11.562571+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {

2022-10-22T17:19:11.562571+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

2022-10-22T17:19:11.562571+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: []

2022-10-22T17:19:11.562572+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

[image: folder structure]

Comment: Could you please show your folder structure?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes, here: [x](https://i.ibb.co/12Hmww3/Screenshot-180.png). Sorry about the double notif, messed up the formatting.

Comment: I don't see `src` folder anywhere

Comment: @KonradLinkowski What's the src folder for? I only ask because the example apps I'm looking at don't seem to use one, so it never crossed my mind.

Comment: Addendum; tried moving index.js to src, and switching the procfile line to web: node src/index.js. Now getting an entirely different error! Will keep fiddling with it.

Comment: Sure, `index.js` can be blank. Or it can not exist, or it can contain code. There's nothing magic about that name. It all depends on how you build your application.

Comment: @joey, Konrad is probably asking about `src/` because you use it in your `Procfile`. Which file actually listens for HTTP requests in your application? Are you using Express somewhere?

Comment: @Chris Oh, my mistake. The boaLogin.js file takes HTTP requests, but the final project will have multiple .js files, so I'm under the impression it shouldn't be the start file. I'll look into Express, though; thank you.